# Simplifying algebraic expression using pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

Given the following expression

```
expr = x Cos[y] + x^(2 y) + x y + Sin[x^2 z Cos[y]];
```

I would like to achieve the following output:

```
output = x Cos[y]^2 + Sin[x^2 z Cos[y]^2]
```

I tried it with case

```
Cases[expr, t : _Cos :> t^2, All]
```

but the result is not what I expected.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You want to get all terms that contain `Cos` somewhere in them, and then replace each `Cos[...]` with `Cos[...]^2`?

Comment: @Domen That is precisely right. But I wanted to do that by matching patterns for the Head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need two patterns?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr = x Cos[y] + x^(2 y) + x y + Sin[x^2 z Cos[y]];
pat = {h_.*f_[g_.*(t : _Cos)] :> h*f[g*t^2], g_.*(t : _Cos) :> g*t^2};
Plus @@ Flatten[Cases[expr, #] & /@ pat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatives does not work, since Cases matches on first Alternative found, not all of them.

Here is another way using replace, which I think is simpler

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr = x Cos[y] + x^(2 y) + x y + Sin[x^2 z Cos[y]];
expr = DeleteCases[expr, x_ /; FreeQ[x, _Cos]];
expr /. Cos[t_] :> Cos[t^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]